# How can I have Identity column with CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to have the orderNumber columns to have IDENTITY but I keep getting this error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 205
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IDENTITY'

My code:

```
WITH CTE_Territory1Sales (OrderNumber, SalesPersonID, TerritoryID)
AS
(
    SELECT   
        IDENTITY(int, 100, 25), [SalesPersonID], [TerritoryID] 
    FROM    
        [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
    WHERE   
        SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL AND TerritoryID = 1
)
```

Comment: `IDENTITY` can only be used as an additional attribute when defining an `INT` (or `BIGINT`)  column in a table - you cannot use it like this - just not supported

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve here ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use Identity in CTE but if you want to generate a sequential number, you can use the Row_Number() function like below -

```
WITH CTE_Territory1Sales ( OrderNumber, SalesPersonID, TerritoryID )
AS
(
    SELECT  Row_Number() over (order by SalesPersonID) RowNum, [SalesPersonID],[TerritoryID] 
    FROM    [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
    WHERE   SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL AND TerritoryID = 1
)
select * from CTE_Territory1Sales
```

Answer (score 2):

Never been able to use IDENTITY in a CTE. But have you considered creating a temporary table instead?

Temp tables generate their own statistics and you can configure indexes, etc. Useful if your Territory1Sales dataset going to be large.

```
CREATE TABLE #Territory1Sales
(
    [OrderNumber] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (100,25)
    , [SalesPersonID] INT
    , [TerritoryID] INT
) ;
GO

INSERT  INTO #Territory1Sales ( [SalesPersonID], [TerritoryID] )
SELECT  [SalesPersonID], [TerritoryID]
FROM    [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
WHERE   [SalesPersonID] IS NOT NULL 
    AND [TerritoryID] = 1 ;
GO

-- execute whatever queries you need to against the temp table

DROP TABLE #Territory1Sales ;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `IDENTITY` in a **CTE** or **SELECT**

1. You can use it by inserting into a temp table.

```
SELECT 
    IDENTITY (INT, 1, 1) AS ID,
    [SalesPersonID], [TerritoryID] into #T
FROM   
    [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
WHERE 
    SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL AND TerritoryID = 1
```

2. You can use `SEQUENCE`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.sequence
AS INT
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1 

SELECT 
    NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sequence as ID,
    [SalesPersonID], [TerritoryID]
FROM 
    [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
WHERE 
    SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL AND TerritoryID = 1
```

3. Use `Row_Number()` function in your query